# Problems with MPAndroidChart configuration. Xaxis, bar background

Tags: android, android-layout, charts, view, mpandroidchart

my dear StackOverflow community! I would really appreciate help from a person who has used MPAndroidChart for a while or just knows the things about this library.

This post can be a bit long, but please if you know some tips or tricks, or you have used this library - **please read a bit, maybe you can save me a lot of time and help solve at least one problem**.

So, making the long story short. 
What I am trying to achieve

[image]

And what I have right now.

[image]

Don't laugh just yet.

So I have three problems:

1. Set the background of the bars as a Drawable item. I have three drawable gradient backgrounds, no shapes or strokes, just plain gradient, which I want to set as background for my bars.
2. The distance between bars. I haven't succeeded in setting the distance between bars like in the first picture. I don't know how to properly make bars in one DataSet near each other and set this space between DataSets.
3. The X-axis. I know that it has been a pain in the ass for a lot of people to set x-axis labels. I am using IndexAxisValueFormatter and passing it a List of Strings, which I want to set them as my labels.

For example, I have 5 data sets with 3 bars in each. How should I properly configure my BarChart?

Thank you in advance, lovely StackOverflow community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2) To set space between datasets, use `groupBars` method. It allows setting:

- space between bars in same data set
- space between datasets

  ```
  mChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

  final ArrayList<BarEntry> bar1List = new ArrayList<>();
  final ArrayList<BarEntry> bar2List = new ArrayList<>();
  final ArrayList<BarEntry> bar3List = new ArrayList<>();
  final ArrayList<String> xLabels = new ArrayList<>();

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      bar1List.add(new BarEntry(i, (float) randInt()));
      bar2List.add(new BarEntry(i, (float) randInt()));
      bar3List.add(new BarEntry(i, (float) randInt()));

      xLabels.add("entry " + i);
  }

  // set color for bars
  BarDataSet bar1Set = new BarDataSet(bar1List, "Bar 1");
  bar1Set1.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));

  BarDataSet bar2Set = new BarDataSet(bar2List, "Bar 2");
  bar2Set.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 255, 0));

  BarDataSet bar3Set = new BarDataSet(bar3List, "Bar 3");
  bar3Set.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 255));


  // for 3 bars in a dataset, this must equals "1" :
  //     (barWidth + barSpace) * 3 + groupSpace = 1

  // space between data sets
  final float groupSpace = 0.25f;
  // space between bars in same data set
  final float barSpace = 0.05f;
  // width of bar
  final float barWidth = 0.2f;

  BarData barData = new BarData(bar1Set, bar2Set, bar3Set);
  barData.setBarWidth(barWidth);

  // make this BarData object grouped
  barData.groupBars(0, groupSpace, barSpace); // start at x = 0

  mChart.setData(barData);
  ```

3) To show list of strings as x-axis label, create `IAxisValueFormatter` & set it as `ValueFormatter` of x-axis.

```
    XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xAxis.setTextSize(12);
    xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0);
    xAxis.setAxisMaximum(barData.getXMax() + 1);

    // xLabels is populated in code above in (2)

    // show user-defined string
    IAxisValueFormatter xAxisFormatter = new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            if (value >= 0 && value <= xLabels.size() - 1) {
                return xLabels.get((int) value);
            }

            // to avoid IndexOutOfBoundsException on xLabels, if (value < 0 || value > xLabels.size() - 1)
            return "";
        }
    };

    xAxis.setValueFormatter(xAxisFormatter);
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response
I've tried your solution #2 and it grouped my data. But not exactly how I want it to be grouped. Plus the colors are not, how they should be now. 
I will attach a screenshot, maybe you could give me some advice.
Thank you in advance!!

http://prntscr.com/imlv7o

Comment: To set color for bars, use `bar1Set1.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));`. My answer is updated to reflect this.

Comment: I've tried solution #3. I have a list of 5 Bar Entries and List of 5 String objects. I'm making everything like you've suggested and it doesn't work :(

Comment: Okay, so a quick update. It groups the data for 3 data sets. However, you've added a comment that we need to be strict to some formula to show 3 datasets in a single bar. 
Do you have any suggestions about how could I exactly display the bars as they are in the image in first post. (The first one). With medium sized bars and large distance between datasets.
But still thank you a lot about your help!

Comment: This is my current code: https://gist.github.com/Progern/f65381775ef28e5342342ccb24b3964d

And this is a screenshot of what is now on screen:
http://prntscr.com/io0cty

Comment: From your screenshot: https://prnt.sc/io0cty , I see you already able to group 3 bars in a dataset, & set large distance among datasets. Congratulations & welldone! If you find my answer helpful, why not mark it as answer then.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do you can achieve this by following below example:

```
    float barWidth;
    float barSpace;
    float groupSpace;

    // (barWidth * 2) + (barSpace * 2) + groupSpace should be equal to one
    barWidth = 0.25f;
    barSpace = 0.05f;
    groupSpace = 0.4f;

    int groupCount = 7;

    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();

    xVals.add("Jan");
    xVals.add("Feb");
    xVals.add("Mar");
    xVals.add("Apr");
    xVals.add("May");
    xVals.add("Jun");
    xVals.add("Jul");

    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals2 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(0, (float) 2));
    yVals2.add(new BarEntry(0, (float) 3));
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(1, (float) 1));
    yVals2.add(new BarEntry(1, (float) 2));
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(2, (float) 3));
    yVals2.add(new BarEntry(2, (float) 4));
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(3, (float) 6));
    yVals2.add(new BarEntry(3, (float) 5));
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(4, (float) 4));
    yVals2.add(new BarEntry(4, (float) 3));
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(5, (float) 2));
    yVals2.add(new BarEntry(5, (float) 6));
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(6, (float) 5));
    yVals2.add(new BarEntry(6, (float) 7));

    BarDataSet set1, set2;
    set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, "A");
    set1.setColor(getColor("defaultGreen"));
    set1.setValueTextColor(getColor("primaryDark"));
    set1.setValueTextSize(defaultValueTextSize);

    set2 = new BarDataSet(yVals2, "B");
    set2.setColor(getColor("defaultOrange"));
    set2.setValueTextColor(getColor("primaryDark"));
    set2.setValueTextSize(defaultValueTextSize);

    BarData data = new BarData(set1, set2);
    barChart.setData(data);
    barChart.getDescription().setText("No. of Contracts signed in 6 months");
    barChart.getDescription().setTextSize(12);
    barChart.setDrawMarkers(true);
    barChart.setMarker(markerView(context));
    barChart.getAxisLeft().addLimitLine(lowerLimitLine(2,"Minimum",2,12,getColor("defaultOrange"),getColor("defaultOrange")));
    barChart.getAxisLeft().addLimitLine(upperLimitLine(6,"Target",2,12,getColor("defaultGreen"),getColor("defaultGreen")));

    barChart.getBarData().setBarWidth(barWidth);
    barChart.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum( 0 );
    barChart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(0 + 
    barChart.getBarData().getGroupWidth(groupSpace, barSpace) * groupCount);
    barChart.groupBars(0, groupSpace, barSpace);
    barChart.animateY(1000);
    barChart.getData().setHighlightEnabled(true);
    barChart.invalidate();

    //X-axis
    XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
    xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setAxisMaximum(groupCount);
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(xVals));
    //Y-axis
    barChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    YAxis leftAxis = barChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
    //        leftAxis.setSpaceTop(35f);
    leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);

    barChart.getXAxis().setGranularityEnabled(true);
    barChart.getXAxis().setGranularity(1.0f);
    barChart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(set1.getEntryCount());
```

Comment: For further assistance do let me know mate. Happy Coding!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response! As the response of @shuwn yuan tee it works like a charm for a DataSet with 3 bars. 
I was applying it wrong.
But I will check her answer as appropriate one because it was first.
Thank you for you help! I really appreciate that.